# Trouble understanding file scope in C

Tags: c, file, scope

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around files in C, specifically scope and duration. Say I create a file using

```
fopen("random.dat", "w");
```

How long does this file exist for? Does it get deleted once my program is finished running, or is it somehow reset? If I reopen the file further down in my code, only this time with the "r" reading argument, or "a", will I have conflicting streams since I'm opening a file that is already technically opened?

Comment: Just in case: this has absolutely no relation to the standard terms *scope* and *file scope* heavily used in C language terminology.

Comment: Indeed, file scope means: the scope of variables declared outside any function in a C source code file.

Comment: Apologies, I didn't know how to phrase it differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a normal file, just like all the other files on your computer.  It exists until something deletes it, and its contents stay the same until something modifies it.  It's not automatically deleted or "reset" when the program finishes.  (C would be useless as a programming language if it couldn't save data to files that last longer than the program.)

However, since you're opening the file with the "w" option, the file will be truncated (reset to zero length) if it already exists — effectively, `fopen` deletes the existing file and creates a new empty one.  That means that if you run your program a second time, the output from the first run will be replaced with the output from the second.

The effect of opening the same file more than once at the same time is platform-specific.  On Unix/Linux it should work fine, but on Windows it may fail (though I haven't checked).  But if you close the file (e.g. with `fclose`) before opening it again, that should work properly on any system.

Comment: Right, so if create a file in a program, I shut down my IDE, my laptop, etc. and come back tomorrow, the file will still be there, along with its contents? It also seems risky to me then to have a program that creates a file with "w" and then runs functions on/with it, as you'd then be scrapping the file each time you run it, no?

Comment: @David Tamrazov: Yes, the file will be there, assuming the "storage media" is there. If you create a file on a non-persistent RAM drive, then it won't be there. If you create a file on a micro-SD card drive and then a cat swallows the card... well, you get the picture. As for whether it is "dangerous" to overwrite a file: it depends on your intent. Some files are created specifically for temporary purposes, i.e to be overwritten anew each time. None of this has much to do with C language though. Especially the cat.

Comment: Yes, the file will still be there tomorrow.  And yes, the file will be overwritten (and the old contents erased) each time you run your program, but that's often what you want anyway.  If your compiler supports [C11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_%28C_standard_revision%29), you can also open the file in "wx" mode, which means that `fopen` should *fail* if the file already exists, instead of truncating it.  That lets you avoid accidentally overwriting important files.  There are also platform-specific ways to do the same, that work even on old systems that don't support C11.

Comment: All right brilliant, thanks guys. Its strange learning to work with variables that have a lifespan beyond each program execution haha, appreciate the help

Comment: @David Tamrazov: Er... There's no such thing as "variables that have a lifespan beyond each program execution". An external file is not a variable.

Comment: I didn't literally mean a "variable". I'm just saying I'm not used to coding with things that last beyond the single run is all :)

Comment: I'm sure you're already familiar with how files work on a computer. Your source code lasts beyond a single run of your editor, after all.

Answer (score 1):

The term *file scope* is used during compilation of a C program. It has nothing to do with something during execution.

Actually, the term is missleading; a better phrase would be *compilation unit scope*. It describes the visibility of names (variables, functions, structs, ... ) defined outside of a *block (statement)*, i.e. at the outermost level.

For files opened during program execution, they are open actually until closed explicitly, independent from the program structure. However, as you required an object holding a reference to the file, that does restrict visibility to where you have access to this reference (`FILE *` for the stdlib file-functions), either by *scope*, or by explicitly passing it to functions.

A normal file opened/written/closed will dwefinitively not stop existing after the program closes or its reference goes out of scope (how could you store data persistently?), but only if explicitly deleted/unlinked or the filesystem itself is deleted (e.g. for Linux tempfs, which only exists until the OS is shut down). This is called *lifetime*, btw.